# parse javascript text to array

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have following code in js:

```
var poly_line_offset_f5 = L.polyline(
    [[41.716111, 20.722361], [41.7704754, 20.8381323]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#FFA500", "dashArray": "", "dashOffset": null}
).addTo(feature_group_Under110kVLines);

var popup_6cc = L.popup({"maxWidth": "100%"});

var html_a1 = $(' <div id="html_a1" </div> ')[0];
popup_6cc.setContent(html_a1);

poly_line_offset_f5.bindPopup(popup_6cc)
;

poly_line_offset_f5.bindTooltip(
    '<div> VLKIJ_VRUGHTK_4_95:  </div>',
    {"sticky": true}
);
```

For purpose of this question, this code is going to be treated as plain text.
I want to parse this to some kind of array or dataframe or dictionary ( any structured data ) with groups of datasets for each variable ( `poly_line_offset_f5`, `popup_6cc`, `html_a1` ).
Since I am familiar with python, I am exploring [this approach](https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious/), but it looks a bit complicated for me since I am new in parsing.

I need following outputs:

`poly_line_offset_f5`:

```
var x1  y1  x2  y2  dpoly   layer   bindpop html    dbind
poly_line_offset_f5 41.716111   20.722361   41.7704754  20.8381323  {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#FFA500", "dashArray": "", "dashOffset": null}  feature_group_Under110kVLines   popup_6cc   <div> VLKIJ_VRUGHTK_4_95:  </div>'  {"sticky": true}
```

`popup_6cc` :

```
var dict    bind
popup_6cc   {"maxWidth": "100%"}    html_a1
```

`html_a1`:

```
var text
html_a1  ' <div id="html_a1" </div> '
```

If you have any ideas, guidelines for solving this it would be very helpfull.

Comment: Please show all text as text, not as pictures of text.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using `esprima`. Here is PyPi [page](https://pypi.org/project/esprima/).

Example code:

```
from esprima import parseScript

with open("file.js", "r") as file:
    string = file.read()

script = parseScript(string)
print(script)
```

Not sure if you can accomplish everything you want, but it can give you variables and their values.